# Comparation between continued fractions

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

I'm trying to solve the following problem but I'm having some difficulties..

> Let $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_0,b_1,\dots,b_n,b_{n+1}$ be positive integers. Give conditions that make the following statement true:
>   $$[a_0;a_1,\dots,a_n]<[b_0;b_1,\dots,b_n,b_{n+1}]$$

I thing a have to use convergents of the continued fraction but I don't know how. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Left side is between $a_0$ and $a_0 + 1$.
2. $[a_0; a_1, \ldots ] = a_0 + 1/[a1; a_2, \ldots]$

Comment: can you be a little more specific please.

Comment: If $a_0 \ne b_0$, that decides it.  Otherwise, look at
$[a_1;a_2,\ldots]$ and $[b_1;b_2,\ldots]$.